# Generating a waveform like SoundCloud using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, waveform

How to generating a waveform like SoundCloud using ffmpeg?

[image]

Now im reading documentation about showwavespic, colorbalance and drawbox filters, but for me it's to hard. I would like this ▁ ▂ ▇ ▃ ▅ ▂ beautiful style without background.

This is what im using now:

```
ffmpeg -i music.mp3 -filter_complex showwavespic=s=1200x320 wave.png
```

Thank You!

Comment: Oh, sad to know. Can i ask you .. what i need to do to get custom waveform color and transparent background? I need white + transparent and for example #f84aee + transparent background? It's a colorbalance trick? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Niks have to managed to generate these waveforms?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://wavesurfer-js.org/